# how can i understand that all message is sent using Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, tcp, network-programming

Using TCP protocol. Client is Flash. Server is Java (on Linux).

Is there anyway to understand if a message is successfully sent to target server in client (Actionscript 3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using the Socket class for this, which will broadcast events. To make sure your data is sent succesfully, have the server send back some confirmation data. The Socket class will broadcast a ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA event which you can listen for.

Refer to the [Socket manpage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html)